# Visual Studio Auto Format Curly Brace on Next Line

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am so used to code like this:

```
if (...)
{
   //somecode
}
```

that I simply have to change the following to the above:

```
if (...){
   //somecode
}
```

I get a lot of code from other people that I have to go through and sometimes this is what I get. Is it possible to auto-format that in Visual Studio 2008 for C++?

Now some may think I should get used to it. Believe me, I am trying, but it is very distracting and I hope there is a simple solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VS2008 has a simple formatter (Edit menu, Advanced, Format Selection), but it doesn't move braces.

Check out [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html) and its `--style=ansi` flag.

Comment: +1 astyle is command line application so can be simply integrated into VS2008 as external tool.